# Condition based command parameters filling in prompt

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to fill the parameters in conditional based in the command prompt in *CMD Creation in as400.

> let say we have 3 parms (A B C)

PARM KWD(A) TYPE (*CHAR) VALUE(A1 A2) LEN(11) MIN(1)

PARM KWD(B) TYPE (*CHAR) VALUE(B1) LEN(11) MIN(1)

PARM KWD(C) TYPE (*CHAR) VALUE(C1) LEN(11) MIN(1)

Here I entered the first value is A1 in Parm A. Now I want to demonstrate only one field that is Field B.

So next if I entered the value of A2 in the field A.so now I want to demonstrate the field is C.so how can I create the logic with based on these conditions.

Comment: What does this have to do with [ibm-integration-bus] and [ibm-mobilefirst]?

Comment: I'm afraid I am having trouble understanding the question. Please try editing your question so that it includes examples of how you would like to call this command. Don't just describe it in words, please give the command a name, and then give actual samples of real input that we would type at the command line, if you could create such a command.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the desired outcome in psuedocode?

Answer (score 2):

use the `PMTCTL` command to define a condition. Then use the `PMTCTL` parameter on the `PARM` command to specify the condition under which the parameter is prompted.

```
             CMD        PROMPT('conditional paramters')

             PARM       KWD(A) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(11) RSTD(*YES) +      
                          VALUES(A1 A2) PROMPT('parm a') 
             PARM       KWD(B) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(11) RSTD(*YES) +      
                          VALUES(B1) PMTCTL(COND_A1) PROMPT('parm b')
             PARM       KWD(C) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(11) RSTD(*YES) +      
                          VALUES(C1) PMTCTL(COND_A2) +               
                          PROMPT('parm c')
  COND_A1:   PMTCTL     CTL(A) COND((*EQ A1)) 
  COND_A2:   PMTCTL     CTL(A) COND((*EQ A2))
```

Comment: Yes sir it's working fine thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, if I understand you right you want to fill parameters based on the input of another input field like in savobj below.
[image: SAVOBJ (german)]
To be honest I don't know how to acheive this with cmd but I also do not know if the way you described was the way of the IBM. I would rather guess that this is a common program which works with *noPass and *omit. If this is cool for you you can find further information here:

- [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzasd/doptns.htm)
- [guide how to code with the keywords in RPG](https://www.itjungle.com/2005/01/05/fhg010505-story02/)